# Necesito ayuda con página web errores validación

Tags: html, web, validación

soy nuevo en esto de "programar" y estoy creando una página web,tengo muy poquitos conocimientos,(los estoy adquiriendo poco a poco,llevo menos de una semana),pues bien tengo problemas a la hora de validar mi web en dreamweaver tengo muuuchos errores y no se por donde empezar... si alguien puede ayudarme os agradecería muchisimo vuestra colaboración...,os adjunto los errores

```
|||

Gravedad     Archivo     Descripción     Línea   

|||

Error Bogus doctype.     1   
Error Quirky doctype. Expected <!DOCTYPE html> .     1   
Error Bad value cleartype for attribute http-equiv on element meta .     57  
Error Bad value https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,600,700|Material+Icons for attribute href on element link : Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.     79  
Error A link element with an as attribute must have a rel attribute that contains the value preload .    79  
Error Stray end tag div .    85  
Error Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.     159     
Error An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images .      159     
Error Stray end tag img .    159     
Error Stray end tag a .      160     
Error A slash was not immediately followed by > .    172     
Error End tag had attributes.    172     
Error Stray end tag span< .      172     
Error End tag div seen, but there were open elements.    173     
Error Unclosed element span .    172     
Error End tag nav seen, but there were open elements.    175     
Error Unclosed element div .     170     
Error No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.    206     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    299     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    300     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    301     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    304     
Error CSS: color : #white is not a valid color 3 or 6 hexadecimals numbers.      304     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    305     
Error Duplicate attribute style .    308     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    308     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    309     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    312     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    313     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    316     
Error Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)    317     
Error Stray end tag ul .     319     
Error End tag div seen, but there were open elements.    320     
Error Unclosed element span .    318     
Error No li element in scope but a li end tag seen.      321     
Error Stray end tag ul .     322     
Error Stray end tag div .    327     
Error Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.     334     
Error Stray end tag a .      350     
Error Stray end tag a .      352     
Error Stray end tag a .      353     
Error Stray end tag a .      356
```

Comment: Hola, antes que nada te recomiendo leer un poco sobre [markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para escribir tus preguntas

Sobre los errores, ¿Puedes abrir tu proyecto web en el navegador? En las lineas que compartes con nosotros podemos ver que hay varios errores de sintaxos en html, estás siguiendo algún tutorial o artículo ?

Comment: Si,puedo visualizar la página web,pero he leido que si una web tiene muchos errores el SEO, es peor, y queda mas aestetico una web,soy nuevo en esto y no se muy bien aún

Comment: Podrías por favor compartir tu documento HTML, para poder entender mejor el origen de los problemas ? Puedes editar tu pregunta y mostrarnos el código

Comment: ¿que copio la web entera o solo las partes de los errores?,estoy aprendiendo por lecturas y utilizando plantillas y modificando y haciendo

Comment: Como te comenté, muchos de los errores que tienes son de sintaxis, puedes darte cuenta leyendo cada linea de los errores que muestras. Es muy fácil ubicar el error, Leer a partir de donde pone `Error`, seguido del error, y al final pone el número de la linea en la que se encuentra el "error"

Comment: Una buena forma de saber por qué ocurren los errores, es copiando el error y buscandolo en el navegador, por ejemplo uno de los primeros errores que tienes es `Stray end tag img`, lo buscas en internet, y te mostrará a que se debe al modo en el que está cerrando la etiqueta de la imagen, dependiendo de la versión HTML que estés usando

Comment: tengo un problema,la web es muy extensa y no me deja poner todo el codigo,que puedo hacer :/

Comment: medina podrias decirme como averiguo eso en dreamweaver? no veo donde pone pone eso :P,uso html5-responsive

Comment: Podrías proporcionar la primera línea de código de tu documento ? Ahí en donde debe mostrar la declaración del DOCTYPE

Comment: <!doctype html lang="es-ES"> ahi lo llevas!

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo, es lo que te dejé en el último comentario, tienes muchos errores, que en realidad son detalles de sintaxis, entre ellos tienes etiquetas sin cerrar, atributos donde no van, mal uso de otras etiquetas, elementos no cerrados o elementos sin apertura


Haz como te digo, cada línea te muestra el error y en donde localizarlo, puedes copiar el error y buscarlo en el explorador, te aseguro que todos tienen respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda@A.Medina (y a todos los demas!!:) <3 ) ^_^ iré buscando los errores poco a poco a ver si soluciono este caos xD

Comment: Te comento que aclarado el punto de que esos mensajes de errores te ocurren por *typos* que esta relacionado a escribir mal el código entonces tu pregunta terminará cerrada